# java library for outputting to csv- what are the special cases that need to be handled, to output data to csv format

Tags: java, csv

I am looking for a (preferably)free Java library that outputs data stored in variable (viz list of list) to a csv file.

I saw a commercial library by RiceBridge where they talk of all kinds of special cases that their library takes care of -- is there any free library that also does the same?

Alternatively, what are the special cases that I should handle, if I want to create my own csv writer library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading csv is difficult, writing is not. You can just enquote all values with double quotes and replace double quotes in your field values by double double quotes.

Comment: As you have to handle very many special cases, in particular since escaping with double quotes is optional. You cannot simply split the input at the delimiters (e.g. the comma). You have to start from the beginning of the file and count the double quotes. A delimiter is "delimiting" if and only if it is preceded by an even number of double quotes -- example: "this",are,"four, not five",fields. In addition, even newlines can be quoted by double quotes, hence you cannot be sure that a line end always is the end of a record without having counted all double quotes from the beginning of the file.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using http://commons.apache.org/csv/ at the moment, works fine for my purposes, i.e. parsing. Worth a look.

Answer (score 2):

[Super CSV](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net) is a free open source Java CSV API.

It has 4 [writing implementations](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/writers.html): as well as writing from a List, you can also write from a Map or POJO.

We (the Super CSV team) have just released a [new version](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/release_notes.html) with a powerful Dozer extension - allowing you to map POJOs with nested properties and by index (for arrays/Collections). It also offers a wide variety of [processors](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/cell_processors.html) you can use to transform and validate your data.

As JohnB has said, writing CSV is relatively easy and reading is [quite complicated](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/csv_specification.html). Saying that, I'd still recommend using a library for writing. It's free and open source! And instead of rolling your own solution, why not consider contributing to an open source one? That way others can benefit from your ideas :)

Answer (score 0):

http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/
is a Java API worth taking a look